# Django test server gives 404 to static files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

In production, I'm using NGINX and set an alias for static files, so this is fine.

However, in test server mode, I get 404 for all of the static files.  They are located in the base of the project and here are my relevant settings:

```
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

And here is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'home.views.home', name='home'),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When running the test server, I try to get `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/home/img/logo.png`, which is located in `$BASE_DIR/static/home/img/logo.png`, but get 404.

```
'home/img/logo.png' could not be found
```

and in the test server log

```
[03/Feb/2015 17:49:08] "GET /static/home/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1655
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set your URLs up to server static files? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: I think `STATIC_DIRS` should be `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: @HåkenLid, that's the answer, thanks!  Please add it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STATIC_DIRS` should be `STATICFILES_DIRS`